# Trying to POST data with $resource in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm worried that I am just making a really stupid mistake, but I've been at this for a few hours to no avail.

I'm in the process of learning the MEAN stack, and I am making progress. Right now I am making a little fake TaskList CRUD app to get all the basics down, and so far I can GET no problem, but that's it.

My factory:

```
.factory('Tasks', function ($resource) {

    var tasks = $resource('tasks',{},{update:{method: 'POST', isArray:true}});
    return tasks;
}
```

My controller:

```
.controller('TasklistCtrl', function ($scope, Tasks) {

    $scope.taskList = Tasks.query();

    $scope.addTask = function(){

        $scope.taskList.push($scope.newTask);
        Tasks.update({}, $scope.newTask);

};
```

And my html is pretty straight forward for now

```
<table>
    <th><h2>Fun Practice Task List!</h2></th>
    <tr ng-repeat="task in taskList | orderBy:'title'">
        <td><h3>{{ task.title }}</h3> </td> <td><h3>{{ task.task }}</h3></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newTask.title"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newTask.task"/>

    <h2>{{ newTask }}</h2>

    <button type="submit" ng-click="addTask()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The backend has express working it's magic, tied to mongodb.

Right now a POST is being sent successfully, but it's just sending the original GET right back to the server. Originally I just had

Tasks.save(); instead of

Tasks.update({}, $scope.newTask);

But that didn't work either. I am pretty sure I'm just not understanding something fundamental, and I am going to go through reading more of the documentation/watching more tutorials/practicing - but hopefully someone can give me some advice in the meantime! Using Angular 1.2 btw.

**edit:**

So taking Zack's suggestion, my controller now looks like:

```
.controller('TasklistCtrl', function ($scope, Tasks) {

  $scope.taskList = Tasks.query();

  $scope.addTask = function(){

    Tasks.save($scope.newTask, function(data) {
      $scope.taskList.push(data);
    });

};
```

However, while I see successful posts being sent, on observation the post is just the exact same data I get from Tasks.query(). 'data' in the save callback is the same data, unchanged. Where am I going wrong here, why is scope.newTask not being sent back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Tasks.save($scope.newTask, function(data) {
    $scope.taskList.push(data);
});
```

In place of these two:

```
$scope.taskList.push($scope.newTask);
Tasks.update({}, $scope.newTask);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately I get this error

TypeError: Object function Resource(value){
        copy(value || {}, this);
      } has no method 'post'
    at Object.$scope.addTask

So it looks like 'post' isn't a method of $resource?

Comment: Thanks! I think it's -kind- of working, but I must be doing something wrong because nothing is actually happening the way it's supposed to. The data being sent by the post just seems to be the data that was pulled by the get (Or rather, data being sent with save() is the same as the data I grabbed with query()). So I might have to restructure this whole thing - regardless, your answer solved my immediate problem, even if it just exposed another one for me :P.